# Error Logging into Xamarin account from Xamarin Studio on Mac

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Currently I have been trying to get some new components for my Xamarin.iOS project but every time I try to log into my Xamarin Developer account from within Xamarin Studio, I receive the following error messages:

```
System.Exception: Could not load machine data: warning MT0061: No Xcode.app specified (using --sdkroot), using the system Xcode as reported by 'xcode-select --print-path': /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
error MT0052: No command specified.
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors) [0x00243] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3055/f3c0d982/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:702 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService+<GenerateFullWorkflowSequence>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x0043a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3055/f3c0d982/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:588 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationWorkflowStep step) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3055/f3c0d982/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:473 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog+<StartSpinnerTaskAndScheduleContinuation>c__AnonStorey4.<>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x0005b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3055/f3c0d982/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:587
```

Does anyone know if there are any ways to fix this?
I have spent some time now looking through posts but have not found a solutions that works for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi,

I'm from Xamarin Support. Could you email this issue into xamarin support from the email that is associated with your Xamarin account?

Comment: Sorry, hit return by mistake.

The "Could not load Machine Data" error is a common generic error. When you email in, please send your IDE logs, version info [2], and what you were doing when you got this error. It looks like you were trying to install a component? 

[1] Email support: hello@xamarin.com
[2] https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs-

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you do not have Xcode installed. Are you able to ensure that Xcode is installed don the system? You can get Xcode from the Mac App Store.